# Смена экранов горизонтальным скроллом при прокрутке мыши

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Ребят нужна помощь , наверное вы слышали про смену экранов одностраничного сайта, но во всех источниках смена происходит вертикально , а мне нужно горизонтальном , вообщем это будет якобы большой слайдер только слайды будут меняться не при нажатии на кнопку или клике, а именно при **прокрутке мыши**

Comment: Вы не догадываетесь как это реализуется или в чем вопрос заключается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использую для подобного плагин fullPage.js.
Вот [пример](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html#firstPage) . Там же можно скачать и посмотреть документацию